# what is the command to know what program is using more process in linux?

Tags: process

i would like to know the command for the programs having more process in linux.

```
top - 05:56:00 up 1203 days, 21:29,  1 user,  load average: 1.08, 1.14, 0.88
Tasks: 1142 total,   2 running, 1139 sleeping,   0 stopped,   1 zombie
Cpu(s):  2.7%us,  0.4%sy,  0.0%ni, 96.3%id,  0.0%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.6%si,  0.0%st
Mem:  132128620k total, 131312592k used,   816028k free,   530768k buffers
Swap:  4194296k total,        0k used,  4194296k free, 12164416k cached
```

Comment: You are showing the output of `top`, so that's a good start. See also `ps -ax -o pid,pcpu,comm | less`.

Comment: thanks for your reply, may i know the command for top 10 programs having more processes?

Comment: You can install `htop` that provides a more user friendly interface than Top, and that can be managed with the mouse (not sure that it's what you want thought, that's why I only answer in comment)

Answer (score 1):

To get the 10 processes that are currently using the most CPU, you may use the command

```
ps -ax -opid,pcpu,user,comm --sort=-pcpu | head -n 11
```

This works at least on Ubuntu Linux and produces a list of process IDs, percentage of CPU, the user name of the user running the process, and the command name.

The `--sort=-pcpu` flag used here tells `ps` to sort the result in descending order and the `head` gives you the first 11 lines of output (the header and 10 processes).   For example:

```
   PID %CPU USER     COMMAND
 20975  2.5 100113   mongod
  4268  0.8 root     lxcfs
  3956  0.3 root     txg_sync
133411  0.3 100115   mongod
     8  0.2 root     rcu_sched
   187  0.2 root     kswapd0
  3462  0.2 root     z_wr_iss
  3463  0.2 root     z_wr_iss
  3464  0.2 root     z_wr_iss
  3465  0.2 root     z_wr_iss
```

For more information, see the manual for `ps` on your system (`man ps`).

Comment: Great!  can i get a command for having total processes count in it for each program.?